# How to solve maximum recursion depth exceeded when autoloading one to one columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy, autoloader

I am tying to link two databases via a one to one relationship. One is already establlished the other db is dynamic in terms of the number of columns (except for the key column).

The following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data/items.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Items(db.Model):
    item_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40)) 

    item_embeddings = db.relationship('ItemEmbeddings', backref='items', uselist=False,lazy='dynamic') 
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Item {}>'.format(self.item_id)

class ItemEmbeddings(db.Model):
        item_id = db.Column('item_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('items.item_id'), primary_key=True)

        __table_args__ = {
            'metadata':db.metadata,
            'autoload_with': db.engine,
            'extend_existing': True,

        }
```

yields this error:

```
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 855, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 645, in foreign_keys
    return self.foreign_keys
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 855, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 643, in foreign_keys
    self._init_collections()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Should i solve this by setting some ForeignKey constraint?
The db does not exist yet, so i run db.create_all after importing the model. is there some solution to make this work?